# How to integrate an equation with respect to $y$ instead of $x$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

So I need to integrate from the line $y=1$ to the line $y=e$ for the function $y=e^x$.

I did the following but the answers say otherwise, also the answers do not show any steps, they just gave the area.

$\int_1^e e^x dy$ = $\int_1^e ydy$ = $\frac{1}{2}(e^2 -1)$

I wanted to ask where I was going wrong because I am stuck at this point with no clue. Help is appreciated!

Comment: $x = \log(y).~$  Hint: To compute the indefinite integral $\int \log(y) ~dy,~$ ask yourself, what is the $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dy} \left[y\log(y)\right]~$?

Comment: The formulation is unclear. What exactly is it that you want to calculate? Is is the area bounded by the curve $y=e^x$, the $y$-axis, and the line $y=e$?

Comment: @Hans Lundmark yes and  $y =1$ as well

Comment: Giving the value $y=1$ is redundant, since that's where the graph $y=e^x$ intersects the $y$-axis.

Comment: The integral $\int_0^1 y \, dy$ gives [this area](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%3Cy%3Ce%2C+0%3Cx%3Cy). Can you see now what's wrong with your reasoning?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

EDIT 1:

differentiation wrt $x$

$$ y = log x\,; y'= 1/x\;$$

If  we are finding area slices parallel to $y$ axis,

$$ \int x \;dy= x \; \frac{dx}{x}= x + c_1$$

[image]

Evaluating between the graphed abcissas the green area integral evaluates to

$$ (e^{e}-e)$$